# Service Accounts Authentication not working fr Google Drive - Delete a file Case only

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, service-accounts

We are using **Google Service Accounts** in Developers console of **PHP API** for Drive document.

**While checking manually, the owners,editors and then viewers of a document can delete. Then while using Oauth SA, the same viewers or editors of the document cannot delete**

Creating a drive file, sharing a file and then setting a document owner of file which  all functionality are working fine. We are getting issue while deleting a file by Non-owners of document including editors or viewers of document. But If owner of document  deleting means that file deleting without error.

**EXAMPLE:**

**FUNCTION TO GET SERVICE USING SERVICE ACCOUNT**

```
public function get_service_document ($userEmail,$service_id,$scope,$service_filename) {
        $key = file_get_contents('application/models/lib/'.$service_filename);
        $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            $service_id,
            array($scope),
            $key);
        $auth->sub = $userEmail;
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
        return new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    }
```

**FUNCTION FOR DELETING A DRIVE FILE**

```
public  function deleteDriveFiles(){
$userEmail=xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com;
$service_id=796xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com;
$scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive;
$service_filename=xxxxxxxxxx-6088b372ef98.p12;
$this->load->library('Google');
/**GETTING DOCUMENT SERVICE**/
$service = $this->get_service_document();
$fileId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";/** FILE ID OF DOCUMENT**/
try
{
       $service->files->delete($fileId);/**
}
catch(Exception $e){
ECHO $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

**The above function showing Error below error:**

Error calling DELETE https://www.googleapis.com//drive/v2/files/1ZTd7BxmQErlJTr7OE9uEOOPtIko5UOljOlp-9ampYcA: (403) Insufficient permissions for this file

We tried to solve the above issue using below link but no use

[Google PHP Client API: Insufficient Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896018/google-php-client-api-insufficient-permission)

Plz help to solve this issue!

Comment: It doesn't look like it's related to Google App Engine. If not, please remove tag

Comment: thanks Igor, Tag removed

Comment: As far as i know, only the owner can delete a file. The viewers can trash the file though, which would be the same action that you would do in the UI. Try trashing the file from the viewer account to see if that works for you.

Comment: Gerardo, I tried to trash the file using Service Account. I can trash if i m the file owner. but i cannt trash if i m viewer.I  need using SA only to remove file from G Drive both owner and viewer.Plz Help me how to solve this

Comment: Gerardo, Plz explain how the viewer can trash file manually

Comment: plz any one help me to solve this.