# Google Drive - need to get email address from OAuth (or somewhere)

Tags: google-drive-api

I've read as many posts and tried as many as I could get working and finally got  partial answer - I get a return of the user info, but it does not contain the email address I was looking for in the first place.

```
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE,
        Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL,
        Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_PROFILE,
        Google_Service_Oauth2::PLUS_ME)
));
```

NOTE: I know some may not be required, but better safe than sorry right..??..

```
$accessToken = "{\"access_token\":\"ya29.CjR9A6X75 bla bla bla 02913}";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);
$client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->setState($userId);
$client->setAccessType('offline');

// set the accessToken
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$googleOAuth  = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$result = $googleOAuth->userinfo->get();

var_dump($result);
```

The dump of $result has some info but not email....

snippet of $result =

```
  ["locale"]=>
  string(2) "en"
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "Fred Flintstone"
  ["email"]=>
  NULL
  ["id"]=>
  string(21) "1111111111111111111111"
  ["picture"]=>
  string(92) "https://bla blabla/photo.jpg"
  ["verifiedEmail"]=>
  NULL
```

Can anyone shed some light on 'why' I'm not getting the email returned, I really need it.  Or maybe some suggestions that I may not have already tried?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Found the following https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get#http-request and I do get back the email address, the specific request is: GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?fields=user&key={YOUR_API_KEY}.  Is there a way (I'm using PHP) to setup and get this info  such as $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$about = $service->about->get();

Comment: I try that and I get an error return -- PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about: (403) Insufficient Permission' in /var/treering/html/api/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110

Comment: Try to add this scope "`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly`" in your code. Like the answer in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896018/google-php-client-api-insufficient-permission). Also make sure you enable both the *Drive API* and *Google Drive API* in your Developer console.

Comment: Tried adding the new SCOPE, didn't work for me, same issue. I searched through the google source and did not find that scope string anywhere in my sources.  When I look under 'Google Apps APIs' there is a link which says 'Drive API' when I click it, it says 'Google Drive API' - it's enabled

Comment: Still stuck - From the doc on OAuth - https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth - the scope, which I'm (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) using should give complete access - yet I get permission access when attempting to retrieve the email address.  Makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer that worked for me...  I now get an email address, my changes are as follows to the original code above.

Used these SCOPES

```
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE,
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE,
    Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL)
));
```

// get the email address

```
$googleOAuth  = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$email = $googleOAuth->userinfo->get()->email;
```

Thanks for the help & looks

John